# Get percentage of each unique value in column (mySQL)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to come up with a query that will find all the unique values in a particular column and then count the number of instances of each unique value and give back that count and the percentage for each unique value versus the total number of values.

Here's what I have, but it's not working as it only gives me the first unique item, not all the possible options.

```
select 
`column1`
, ROUND( 
        (count(`column1`)* 100 / (select count(*) from full_db3 
where `exuid` in ('e7dfb4dd-0cd2-44df-bd35-6ecc9a061756','56baea00-253b-428e-88fc-9969688ea9c8'))
      ), 2)
  as Percentage
from full_db3 where `exuid` in ('e7dfb4dd-0cd2-44df-bd35-6ecc9a061756','56baea00-253b-428e-88fc-9969688ea9c8')
```

What this gives me now is the first unique value in `column1` and `Percentage` as 100%.

I'm going to be passing in `exuid` values dynamically, so it'll always be a different number, so either I have to count the number of values I'm passing into this before I pass it or the query has to count them somewhere. Not quite sure how to do either.

Comment: if you group by the unique field and use count on it, it will give you all the unique values and their counts

Comment: The group by worked to get the unique values and percent, but not sure how to use count as you've described.

Comment: select count(column1) will give you the count of occurrences for that unique value when used with group by

Comment: so basically you just add `count(column1)` in your select and add `group by column1` at the end of your query and you should be good to go

Comment: Thanks...got it working.

Answer (score 1):

you need to group by the column you want the count for. Then divide that number by the total number of rows in the table using a subquery:

> select columnA, count(*), (COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable)) * 100 FROM myTable group by columnA;

Comment: where does this fit into my original query?

Comment: That was an example of how you need to modify your query. Add "group by column1" to the end of your query and then also add select count(*) as a third column in your select statement.